# SQL many-to-many select help needed

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables

**Bid_customer**

```
|bidkey | customerkey
|  1    | 1
|  1    | 2
|  1    | 3
```

**customer_groups**

```
| groupkey | customerkey 
|    1     |      1
|    1     |      2
|    1     |      3
```

What I'm trying to get is a result that will look like

```
| bidkey | groupkey
|    1   |      1
```

I've tried a cursor and joins but just don't seem to be able to get what i need any ideas or suggestions

EDIT: customers can belong to more that one group also

Comment: Do you have primary keys on the customer groups and bid customer table?

Comment: the bids table does but the group table does not this data came from postgres

Comment: i could add one to the groups i guess

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it! Then you don't need any of those messy `<br>` and `&nbsp;` tags anymore, either!

Comment: right now MSSQL but it was a postgres DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have a working Many-to-Many relationship in a database you need to have an intermediary table that defines the relationship so you do not get duplicates or mismatched values.

This select statement will join all bids with all groups because the customer matches.

```
Select bidkey, groupkey
From customer_groups
Inner Join bid_customer
Where customer_groups.customerkey = Bid_customer.customerkey
```

**Hers is a sample Many to Many Relationship:**

[image: Many To Many Relationship]

**For your question:**
You will need another table that joins the data. For example, `GroupBids`

`customer_groups` and `bid_customer` would have a one-to-many relationship with `GroupBids`

You would then do the following select to get your data.

```
Select bidkey, groupkey 
From bid_customer 
inner join GroupBids 
   ON bid_customer.primarykey = GroupBids.idBidKey
inner join customer_groups 
   ON customer_groups.primarykey = GroupBids.idCustomerGroupkey
```

This would make sure only *related* groups and bids are returned

Comment: i tried this already, and just again now, it seems to have duplicate values and the number of records  returned are higher than the number of total bids

Comment: @AndrewJackson I'm sorry to be the bearer of bad news here. But if there is some a many-to-many relationship you usually have to have an intermediary table to define the relationship otherwise you will get duplicates because of the way the join works.  [Sample Image of Many-to-Many relationship](http://techrepublic.com.com/i/tr/cms/contentPics/associatetables-5285168-d.gif)

Comment: i know and that's my problem im takeing this data from an old system to a new system which deals with many to many correctly, but i need to migrate the data

Comment: How are the relationships defined on the current system?

Comment: You may need to step the application to figure out how those relationships are inferred to be able to build a select statement to migrate the data.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure who meaningful your sample data is. However following is a simple example.

Query:

```
select distinct b.bidkey, g.gkey
from bidcus b
inner join cusgroup g
on 
b.cuskey = g.cuskey
and g.gkey = 10;
```

Results:

```
BIDKEY  GKEY
1       10
```

Reference: [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6bac6/1)

Comment: i tried this it kind works, well i put it in a cursor  ran it and i gave me 3million results iv updated your fiddle to show you what i mean [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2a2be/1)

Comment: Let us know if you need any help on defining your new table structure. Usually one table will be the so called *transaction* table with many to many relationship. However all tables will respect the referential integrity where you will have your primary keys, foreign keys set up well for your transaction table to navigate without redundancies. That's the whole point of having a relational db schema :) I noticed your fiddle update as well.